# Can't access external harddrive in OSX

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure, unmount

For some reason i can't access my external HDD anymore. It's not showing up in Finder, although i can see it in the Volumes folder and in Disk Utility app.

When i access the HDD from terminal and try to list the files via ls I get permission denied. I tried running

sudo chmod 755 myHDD

now ls returns nothing at all, like an empty folder. At this point I figured the first step is to try to unmount it correctly, which i tried in various ways:

Via Disk Utility: Failed and wants me to make sure nothing is in use on the HDD.

In terminal i tried these methods:

```
diskutil unmountDisk force myHDD
```

"Unmount Failed"

```
sudo umount /dev/disk1
```

"umount: /dev/disk1 not currently mounted", but it still exists in Volumes/myHDD

```
hdiutil detach /dev/disk1
```

"hdiutil: detach: timeout for DiskArbitration expired"

```
hdiutil eject /dev/disk1
```

"hdiutil: detach: timeout for DiskArbitration expired"

As you can see nothing is working for me. I can't unmount it, and when i unplug it form the computer it persists in Disk Utility.

All helps and tips are greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Tried with to repair the disk from Disk Utility with Tuxera NTFS and got this error message:

> Tuxera NTFS could not mount /dev/disk2s1
>   at /Volumes/VERBATIM HD because the following problem occurred:
>
> Aligned I/O enabled.
>   CBCIO enabled.
>   WARNING: ReadFully - I/O error while reading from file (5: "Input/output error")
>   WARNING:   failed at: pread(3, 0x100580000, 282624, 17980981248);
>   WARNING:   bytesRead=0
>   ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
>   Failed to read $UpCase, unexpected length (-1 != 131072).
>   __ntfs_volume_release(): Inode 10 still have 1 references.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/rdisk2s1': Input/output error
>   NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
>   SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
>   then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
>   important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
>   it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
>   /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
>   for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with FileSystem

Are you using NTFS filesystem? Notice that OSX needs some special software to work with this FileSystem and I had some problems with it in the past.

If you are using NTFS, try to uninstall your NTFS software and install it again.

Comment: Thank you for the input. It is indeed NTFS filesystem, but the weird part is that it has been working for over a year, without external NTFS software (only readable though).